# How to check if any of the processes in a list, is running?

Tags: python

I need to check if any of the following processes is running: script1.py,  script2.py,  script3.py

But the example below only checks if one of those processes is running.

```
import os
process_name= "script1.py"  # change this to the name of your process

tmp = os.popen("ps -Af").read()

if process_name not in tmp[:]:
    print "The process is not running."
else:
    print "The process is running."
```

Comment: Loop over all three possibilities and check for each? If you don't understand `for` loops, you need to talk to your teacher, or at least run through a complete Python tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
import os
process_names= ["script1.py", "script2.py", "script3.py"]  # change this to the name of your process

tmp = os.popen("ps -Af").read()
for process_name in process_names
    if process_name not in tmp[:]:
        print ("The {0} is not running.".format(process_name)) #this is in python 3x style
    else:
        print ("The {0} is running.".format(process_name))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
import os 
process_names= ["script1.py","script2.py","script3.py"]
# you can modify this list as you want
tmp = os.popen("ps -Af").read()

for item in process_name: #this loop iterates through the list of script names
      if item not in tmp[:]: 
           print "The process is not running."
      else:
           print "The process is running."
```

However, I strongly recommend you to learn basics of python, looping and oops concepts before you attempt such low-med complex use cases.

Happy Learning!!